# How to loop to create plots for each hour of day of geospatial data?

Tags: python, matplotlib, gis, geospatial, geopandas

I am trying to create an animated map (by generating multiple plots) of road traffic throughout a week, where the thickness of roads is represented by the volume of traffic at a specific time of day.

This is sort of what I'm looking for (but for each hour of each day):

[image]

The data has a structure that looks like this:

```
HMGNS_LNK_ID                 geometry    DOW  Hour   Normalised Value
         2     MULTILINESTRING ((251...    1     0   0.233623  
         2     MULTILINESTRING ((251...    1     1   0.136391
         2     MULTILINESTRING ((251...    1     2   0.108916
```

`DOW` stands for 'day of the week' (1 = Monday) and so for every `Hour` of each of the 7 days I want to plot the map with roads' thickness by the value `Normalised Value`.

I encounter a problem that when trying to loop with this code:

```
for dow in df['DOW']:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
    day_df = df[df['DOW']==dow]

    for hour in day_df['Hour']:
        day_hour_df = day_df[day_df['Hour']==hour]
        day_hour_df.plot(ax=ax, linewidth=day_hour_df['Normalised Value'])
        plt.savefig("day{}_hour{}.png".format(dow, hour), dpi = 200, facecolor='#333333')
```

The problem is that the figures are saved only for day 1, so until `day1_hour_23` and after that, it comes back to `day1_hour0` and overwrites the plot with something new. I can't figure out why it stops at `DOW` 2.

I'm not even sure if the data structure is correct. I would greatly appreciate any help with that. Please find the full code in my [repo](https://github.com/jankomag/melbourne-road-traffic/blob/main/Melbourne-Traffic.ipynb).

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the way you loop and subset `df`. Let's go through the loop in detail. First time in the outer loop, `dow` will be `1` and `day_df = df[df['DOW']==dow]` will select all rows with `1` in the column `DOW`. Now the inner loop goes through the selected rows and creates `day1_hour0` to `day1_hour23`. Inner loop done, great.

Now we come second time into the outer loop and `dow` is again `1`. `day_df = df[df['DOW']==dow]` will select all rows with `1` in the column `DOW`, i.e., the same set of rows that it used the previous time through the outer loop. So, it (re)writes `day1_hour0` to `day1_hour23` again.

I would suggest using [(geo)pandas.groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html):

```
for dow, day_gdf in df.groupby("DOW"):
    for hour, day_hour_gdf in day_gdf.groupby("Hour"):
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
        print(f"Doing dow={dow}, hour={hour}")
        day_hour_gdf.plot(ax=ax, linewidth=day_hour_gdf['Normalised Value'])
        plt.savefig("day{}_hour{}.png".format(dow, hour), dpi = 200, facecolor='#333333')
        plt.close()
```

Bonus Tip: Checkout [pandas-bokeh](https://github.com/PatrikHlobil/Pandas-Bokeh) if you want to generate interactive graphs with background tiles that can be saved as HTMLs or embedded in jupyter notebooks. The learning curve can be a bit steep with bokeh, but you can produce really nice interactive plots.

Cheers!